# Perspective projection not working as intended

Tags: 3d, graphics, python, pygame, projection

I copied a perspective projection matrix from here (https://jsantell.com/3d-projection/) and applied it to my vertices. It looks ok but without depth. Rotation matrices also work.

When I try to divide all components by the w-component after applying the projection matrix I get some weird geometry. This is what I have understand should be done to apply depth projection.

Below is my code, I'm using python and pygame for drawing the polygons of a cube.

What the cube looks like if I don't divide by w:
[image]

With division:
[image]

````
import pygame
import math 
import copy

pygame.init()

screen_width = 960
screen_height = 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
run = True

class Renderer():
    def __init__(self):
    
        self.cube = [
        [[0, 0, 0, 1],    [0, 1, 0, 1],    [1, 1, 0, 1]],
        [[0, 0, 0, 1],    [1, 1, 0, 1],    [1, 0, 0, 1]],                                 
        [[1, 0, 0, 1],    [1, 1, 0, 1],    [1, 1, 1, 1]],
        [[1, 0, 0, 1],    [1, 1, 1, 1],    [1, 0, 1, 1]],                                       
        [[1, 0, 1, 1],    [1, 1, 1, 1],    [0, 1, 1, 1]],
        [[1, 0, 1, 1],    [0, 1, 1, 1],    [0, 0, 1, 1]],                                         
        [[0, 0, 1, 1],    [0, 1, 1, 1],    [0, 1, 0, 1]],
        [[0, 0, 1, 1],    [0, 1, 0, 1],    [0, 0, 0, 1]],                                          
        [[0, 1, 0, 1],    [0, 1, 1, 1],    [1, 1, 1, 1]],
        [[0, 1, 0, 1],    [1, 1, 1, 1],    [1, 1, 0, 1]],                                         
        [[1, 0, 1, 1],    [0, 0, 1, 1],    [0, 0, 0, 1]],
        [[1, 0, 1, 1],    [0, 0, 0, 1],    [1, 0, 0, 1]]]

        
        for tri in self.cube:
            for point in tri:
                point[0] -= 0.5; point[1] -= 0.5; point[2] -= 0.5
            
        a = screen_height/screen_height
        n = 1
        f = 1000
        t = n * math.tan(math.radians(90/2))
        b = -t
        r = a * t
        l = -r

        self.projection = [
            [(2*n)/(r-l), 0, (r+l)/(r-l), 0],
            [0, (2*n)/(t-b), (t+b)/(t-b), 0], 
            [0, 0, (f+n)/(n-f), (2*f*n)/(n-f)],
            [0, 0, -1, 0]
        ]
        
        self.rot = 0
        self.update_roty()
    
    def update_roty(self):
        self.rotation_y = [
            [math.cos(self.rot), 0, -math.sin(self.rot), 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [math.sin(self.rot), 0, math.cos(self.rot), 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1]]

    def Matrix_MultiplyVector(self, i, m):

        vx = i[0] * m[0][0] + i[1] * m[0][1] + i[2] * m[0][2] + m[0][3]
        vy = i[0] * m[1][0] + i[1] * m[1][1] + i[2] * m[1][2] + m[1][3]
        vz = i[0] * m[2][0] + i[1] * m[2][1] + i[2] * m[2][2] + m[2][3]
        vw = i[0] * m[3][0] + i[1] * m[3][1] + i[2] * m[3][2] + m[3][3]
        
        vx /= vw
        vy /= vw
        vz /= vw
        vw /= vw

        return [vx,vy,vz,vw]

    def draw(self):

        self.rot += 0.0175
        self.update_rotx()
        self.update_roty()
        self.update_rotz()

        a = screen_height/2
        
        for tri in self.cube:

            tricopy = copy.deepcopy(tri)
            proj_points = []

            for i, point in enumerate(tricopy):

                tricopy[i] = self.Matrix_MultiplyVector(tricopy[i], self.rotation_y)
                tricopy[i] = self.Matrix_MultiplyVector(tricopy[i], self.projection)

                tricopy[i][0] *= 50; tricopy[i][0] += a  
                tricopy[i][1] *= 50; tricopy[i][1] += a

                proj_points.append((tricopy[i][0], tricopy[i][1]))

            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, [230,168,50], proj_points, 1)

renderer = Renderer()

while run:

    screen.fill([47,79,83])
    mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    renderer.user_input(keys)

    renderer.draw()

    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()```
````

Comment: Can you show us some screenshots to help readers understand what it means to "look OK but without depth" or in what way your geometry gets "weird" after the perspective divide? It helps if you can contrast this against what you *expect* it to look like — what specifically should be different?

Comment: Yes so here is without dividing by w during vector x matrix mutplication: https://imgur.com/a/ybZSceu

And this is with division:https://imgur.com/a/sfcWDMm

Comment: Please embed the images in your question so they display in-line, rather than as external links.  You can click the ️ icon when editing to embed an image via file browser, URL, or pasting from the clipboard. Visit the [help] if you need any support with markdown formatting. Be sure to replace the "Enter image description here" placeholder text with descriptive text for screen readers.

Comment: It's videos, how do I embedd them?

Comment: Nvm I converted them to gifs

Comment: Looks like you're missing [near plane clipping](https://www.gabrielgambetta.com/computer-graphics-from-scratch/11-clipping.html). Perspective transformation flips vertices to the wrong side when triangles cross the camera plane, so you need to clip those triangles so that you only draw the portion in front of the camera, rather than connecting valid vertices in front of the camera to invalid vertices behind it.

Comment: But the square is not inside the camera? It's quite far away

Comment: I cannot test this right now, but I have a suspicion: you need to transpose the projection matrix. More precisely that you got a matrix in column-major but you are working in row-major order (or the other way around, same difference, you would transpose anyway). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I looked over this quite a bit and it seems it's not that. However I might be wrong since I never studied linear algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a problem of the cube being "inside" the "camera".

I tried before to add += 3 to the z-axis of every triangle but it didn't work. Then I noticed it could only be added **after** the rotation matrix had been applied for some reason, but **before** the projection matrix.

Comment: Adding it before the rotation will cause the cube to orbit a radius of 3 around the origin, rather than rotating around its own center. For that reason, we apply transformations in the order 1. scale, 2. rotate, 3. translate. You can also apply a view transform (the inverse of the camera's transformation matrix) before projecting to make it easier to move the viewpoint around.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes a lot of sense!